# Inserting multiple rows in MS Access at once in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to insert multiple records in MS Access at once, but it says

> Characters found after end of SQL statement.

How do I insert all records at once, here is my code.

Sample records which are in DataTable;

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Clear();
            dt.Columns.Add("STORE_NAM1");
            dt.Columns.Add("STORE_ADD1");
            dt.Columns.Add("STORE_ADD2");
            dt.Columns.Add("PHONE");
            dt.Columns.Add("FAX");
            dt.Columns.Add("ABN_ACN_NO");
            dt.Columns.Add("EMAIL");
            dt.Columns.Add("WEB");
            object[] o = { "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer" };
            dt.Rows.Add(o);
            object[] o2 = { "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer" };
            dt.Rows.Add(o2);
            object[] o3 = { "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer", "Qadeer" };
            dt.Rows.Add(o3);
```

Here is insertion..

```
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionAccess))
    {


        List<string> Rows = new List<string>();
        string sCommand = "";
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            sCommand += "insert into store (STORE_NAM1, STORE_ADD1, STORE_ADD2, PHONE, FAX, ABN_ACN_NO, EMAIL, WEB) values ('"
                + row["STORE_NAM1"].ToString() + "', '" 
                + row["STORE_ADD1"].ToString() + "', '" 
                + row["STORE_ADD2"].ToString() + "', '" 
                + row["PHONE"].ToString() + "', '" 
                + row["FAX"].ToString() + "', '" 
                + row["ABN_ACN_NO"].ToString() + "', '" 
                + row["EMAIL"].ToString() + "', '" 
                + row["WEB"].ToString() + "');";

//if I hard code values, this works fine with one insert
//sCommand = "insert into store(STORE_NAM1, STORE_ADD1, STORE_ADD2, PHONE, FAX, ABN_ACN_NO, EMAIL, WEB) values ('Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer');";

//this does not work with multiple records
//sCommand = "insert into store(STORE_NAM1, STORE_ADD1, STORE_ADD2, PHONE, FAX, ABN_ACN_NO, EMAIL, WEB) values ('Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer'); insert into store(STORE_NAM1, STORE_ADD1, STORE_ADD2, PHONE, FAX, ABN_ACN_NO, EMAIL, WEB) values ('Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer'); insert into store(STORE_NAM1, STORE_ADD1, STORE_ADD2, PHONE, FAX, ABN_ACN_NO, EMAIL, WEB) values ('Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer', 'Qadeer');";


      try
        {
            using (OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand(sCommand, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                int result = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(result +" records inserted");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }

    }
```

I have also tried it with parameterized way.

Comment: Executing mutliple statements like this might make you prone to injection, but that being said, I actually don't see anything wrong with your code.  Have you tried printing out your raw Acesss query to see what it looks like?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867192/multiple-insert-statements-in-one-connection

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I also tried to do with hard coded values, it gives same error

Comment: So if you completely hard code two inserts, it fails?  What about hard coding _one_ insert?  Does that also fail?

Comment: Yes if do it with two it fails and it work fine with 1

Comment: Interesting.  It should be working.  Maybe you have to set a configuration to allow more than one statement in a single connection +1.

Comment: where to set that configuration?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited question regarding hard coded values please look into it

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
sCommand += "insert...
```

To

```
sCommand = "insert...
```

Your first time through the loop the Insert string is fine. After that, it just gets longer and longer. Access wants just one statement per query.

Comment: it means multiples inserts are not allowed in ms access at once ?

Comment: Not that I have used but your execute command is inside your for loop so it is executing on every iteration with the code you presented. You could check for a bulk insert in Access SQL (different from Transact SQL)

Comment: @Mangrio re: "Access wants just one statement per query." - This is correct. The Access database engine simply does not support multiple DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, ...) in a single query.