# How to do two inserts in two different tables in VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to execute two different `INSERT` statements with one click of a button.

But when I try running my code only one of the `INSERT` statements is working at time.

What is the best way to fix this?

```
pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\XXXX\XXXXX.mdb"
connstring = pro
myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
myconnection.Open()

commmand = ("insert into ApplicationData ([lastname], [firstname],[studentbirthday],[gender], [email], [phonenumber], [address], [city], [state], [zip], [dadlastname], [dadfirstname], [momlastname],[momfirstname]) values ('" & NewLastNameText.Text & "', '" & NewFirstNameText.Text & "','" & NewDateTimePicker.Text & "','" & NewGenderText.Text & "','" & NewEmailText.Text & "','" & phone.Text & "','" & NewAddressText.Text & "','" & city.Text & "','" & state.Text & "','" & zip.Text & "','" & NewDadLNtext.Text & "','" & NewDadFNtext.Text & "','" & NewMomLNtext.Text & "','" & NewMomFNtext.Text & "')")
commmand = ("insert into StudentLogin ([username], [password]) values('" & username.Text & "','" & password.Text & "')")
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(commmand, myconnection)

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("lastname", CType(NewLastNameText.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("firstname", CType(NewFirstNameText.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("studentbirthday", CType(NewDateTimePicker.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("gender", CType(NewDateTimePicker.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("email", CType(NewEmailText.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("phonenumber", CType(phone.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("address", CType(NewAddressText.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("city", CType(city.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("state", CType(state.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("zip", CType(zip.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("dadlastname", CType(NewDadLNtext.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("dadfirstname", CType(NewDadFNtext.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("momfirstname", CType(NewMomLNtext.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("momlastname", CType(NewMomFNtext.Text, String)))

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("username", CType(username.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("password", CType(password.Text, String)))

Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    myconnection.Close()
    MsgBox("Student Added")
    NewLastNameText.Clear()
    NewFirstNameText.Clear()
    NewEmailText.Clear()
    NewAddressText.Clear()
    NewDadLNtext.Clear()
    NewDadFNtext.Clear()
    NewMomLNtext.Clear()
    NewMomFNtext.Clear()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Comment: The second assignment to the command variable overwrites the first one. If you want to run multiple insert statements, just separate them with semicolons.  Also, you really should look at parameterizing your queries, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867192/multiple-insert-statements-in-one-connection

Comment: You probably mean two different tables, not two different databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OleDb does not care about the names or our parameters. It only cares about the order they appear in the Sql statment matches the order they are added to the parameters collection.

Concatenating strings in you Sql statement is a bad idea for several reason and is certainly not needed when you are using parameters. The .Add method of the parameters collection is very clever and returns an OleDb parameter object without us having to declare on explicitly. It is always a good idea to include the OleDb data type.

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\XXXX\XXXXX.mdb")
        'Pass the Sql statement and the connection directly to the constructor of the command.
        'Note: this should NOT be an open connection.
        Using StudentCommand As New OleDbCommand("insert into ApplicationData ([lastname], [firstname],[studentbirthday],[gender], [email], [phonenumber], [address], [city], [state], [zip], [dadlastname], [dadfirstname], [momlastname],[momfirstname]) values (lastname, firstname,studentbirthday,gender,email,phonenumber,address,city,state,zip,dadlastname,dadfirstname,momlastname,momfirstname);", cn)
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("lastname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewLastNameText.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("firstname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewFirstNameText.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("studentbirthday", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewDateTimePicker.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("gender", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewDateTimePicker.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewEmailText.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("phonenumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = phone.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewAddressText.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("city", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = city.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("state", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = state.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("zip", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = zip.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("dadlastname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewDadLNtext.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("dadfirstname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewDadFNtext.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("momfirstname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewMomLNtext.Text
            StudentCommand.Parameters.Add("momlastname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NewMomFNtext.Text
            'Open the connection at the last minute
            cn.Open()
            StudentCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()
        End Using 'Disposes StudentCommand
        Using LoginCommand As New OleDbCommand("insert into StudentLogin ([username], [password]) values(@username, @password;", cn)
            LoginCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = username.Text
            LoginCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = password.Text
            cn.Open()
            LoginCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'We don't need to .Close the connection
            'The second End Using will close and dispose the connection
        End Using 'Disposes LoginCommand
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("Student Added")
    NewLastNameText.Clear()
    NewFirstNameText.Clear()
    NewEmailText.Clear()
    NewAddressText.Clear()
    NewDadLNtext.Clear()
    NewDadFNtext.Clear()
    NewMomLNtext.Clear()
    NewMomFNtext.Clear()
End Sub
```

One button click, 2 commands executed.

Of course in a real application you would NEVER save passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Put both commands into the same string

```
Dim command1 = "insert into ApplicationData ([lastname], ... values (?, ?, ...)"
Dim command2 = "insert into StudentLogin ([username], ... values (?, ?, ...)"
commmand = command1 & "; " & command2
```

Btw.: you are adding parameters (which is fine), but did not replace the string concatenation of the commands by parameters. For OLEDB, you have to use positional parameters. I.e., in the SQL text, you have to use a `?` for each parameter. Then you have to add the parameters to the parameter collection in the same order! (The name you are using there is ignored, so it does not matter.)

---

Pass the connection string to the connection when creating it and do not change it afterwards. Always declare the connection in a [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement). It automatically closes and disposes the connection at the end. Note, it is not a problem to create new connection objects every time you use one. Because of connection pooling, the "real" connection will be reused.

```
pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\XXXX\XXXXX.mdb"
Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(pro)
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim command1 = "insert into ApplicationData ([lastname], ... values (?, ?, ...)"
    Dim command2 = "insert into StudentLogin ([username], ... values (?, ?, ...)"
    commmand = command1 & "; " & command2

    ...
End Using ' Automatically closes connection here.
```

Comment: I was under the impression that Access can only execute single statements and will error if characters are encountered after the semicolon.

Comment: @Mary, if this should be the case, you would have to execute `ExecuteNonQuery` twice with two commands, or reuse the same command object, but take care to clear the parameters collection before adding the parameters for the second insert.