# exporting data to ms access accdb from sql takes long time

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

i have an SQL database with stock table that has about 10000 rows i need a code that will copy all the rows to access database file accdb faster. as this code will be run daily.

my code below takes at least 5 minutes to run.

`````````````````
````````````````conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter ada2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select ITEMCODE,DESCRIPTION,ONHAND,COSTEXCL,COSTINCL,PRICEEXCL,PRICEINCL,LASTSOLD,LASTRECEIVED from stmast", conn);

                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                ada2.Fill(dt2);

                for (int M = 0; M < dt2.Rows.Count; M++)
                {
                    DataRow dr2 = dt2.Rows[M];


                    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO stmast(ITEMCODE,DESCRIPTION,ONHAND,COSTEXCL,COSTINCL,PRICEEXCL,PRICEincl,LASTSOLD,LASTRECEIVED)" + " VALUES('" + dr2["itemcode"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["description"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["onhand"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["costexcl"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["costincl"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["priceexcl"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["priceincl"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["lastsold"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["lastreceived"].ToString() + "');", objConn3);
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("done"); ```
`````````````````

Comment: Don't know if that's available to you, but using DAO and `RecordSet.AddNew` this would run in seconds (or milliseconds).

Comment: Pürpose of copy? You kno you can link the sql server table to access and work with live data?

Answer (score 1):

finally found a way out, got a general stored proc that copies table data from SQL to ms access, it works in a blink! 
thanks to Danish Janjua

```
Exec dcp_Export_Table @sSrcTableName  = 'stmast' ,@sDestTableName = 'stmast' ,@sPathName  ='C:\Users\ABRAR AHMED\Desktop\test.mdb'


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM   sysobjects WHERE  name = N'dcp_Export_Table' AND type = 'P')

    DROP PROCEDURE dcp_Export_Table

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dcp_Export_Table

 @sSrcTableName  Varchar(100)

 ,@sDestTableName Varchar(100)

 ,@sPathName  Varchar(255)

AS

/*

Module      : dcp_Export_Table

Description : Export named table to named Access Mdb file

Modification History

====================

Date  Author  Description

--------------- --------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

06-09-2005 Danish Janjua Created

*/

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

--

-- *** Logging & Error Check variables *** --

--

Declare

  @sDbName  sysname  -- Holds the Name of the Database where this procedure is being run

 ,@sProcedureName sysname  -- Procedure name, used for Logging

 ,@sStepName  Varchar(50) -- Step name within procedure, used for logging

 ,@sMessage  Varchar(255) -- Used for Procedure Logging

 ,@iError  Int  -- Error value

 ,@iRetVal  Int  -- Return values returned from SP or XP

 ,@sFirstTimeThru Char(1)

 ,@sColumnName  Varchar(50)

 ,@sTableColumnList Varchar(2000)

 ,@sSqlCommand  nVarchar(2000)

--

-- *** Initialise Process logging variables *** --

--

 Select @sDbName  = DB_NAME()

 Select @sProcedureName = OBJECT_NAME(@@Procid)

 Select @iError  = 0

 Select @iRetVal  = 0

 Set NoCount On

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- STEPA: PROCEDURE BEGIN

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- STEPB: Create a comma delimited list of column names into a string

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Select @sTableColumnList = ''

Select @sFirstTimeThru = 'Y'

Declare dcp_columns_cursor Cursor For

 Select  Column_Name

 From  Information_Schema.Columns

 Where  table_catalog  = @sDbName

 and  table_schema  = 'dbo'

 and table_name  = @sSrcTableName

Open dcp_columns_cursor

Fetch Next From dcp_columns_cursor  Into   @sColumnName

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

Begin

 If @sFirstTimeThru = 'Y'

  Begin

   Select @sTableColumnList = @sColumnName

   Select @sFirstTimeThru = 'N'

  End

 Else   

  Select @sTableColumnList = @sTableColumnList + ',' + @sColumnName

 Fetch Next From dcp_columns_cursor  Into   @sColumnName

End

Close dcp_columns_cursor

Deallocate dcp_columns_cursor

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- STEPC: Export table to Mdb file

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Select @sSqlCommand = 'INSERT INTO OPENROWSET '

      + '(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'','      -- provider

      + '''' + @sPathName + ''' ; ''Admin'' ; '''' '    -- path & access details

      + ', ' + @sDestTableName + ')'      -- destination table

      + ' (' + @sTableColumnList + ') '      -- column names

      + 'Select ' + @sTableColumnList + ' From ' +  @sSrcTableName + ' (NoLock)' -- source query

--

-- Execute it!

--

Execute sp_executesql @sSqlCommand

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- STEPZ: PROCEDURE END

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

NORMALEXIT:

Set NoCount Off

Return

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve performance by grouping INSERT commands and executing them with one single DbCommand.

You can start by changing your code as follow. In this version, you execute one command with 10 INSERT queries every 10 records.

````
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter ada2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select ITEMCODE,DESCRIPTION,ONHAND,COSTEXCL,COSTINCL,PRICEEXCL,PRICEINCL,LASTSOLD,LASTRECEIVED from stmast", conn);

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
ada2.Fill(dt2);
string sqlCmd = "";

for (int M = 0; M < dt2.Rows.Count; M++)
{
  DataRow dr2 = dt2.Rows[M];
  sqlCmd += "INSERT INTO stmast(ITEMCODE,DESCRIPTION,ONHAND,COSTEXCL,COSTINCL,PRICEEXCL,PRICEincl,LASTSOLD,LASTRECEIVED)" + " VALUES('" + dr2["itemcode"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["description"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["onhand"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["costexcl"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["costincl"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["priceexcl"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["priceincl"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["lastsold"].ToString() + "','" + dr2["lastreceived"].ToString() + "');";

  if (M % 10 == 0) 
  {
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sqlCmd); 
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCmd = "";
  }
}

//Executes the last commands
if (sqlCmd  != "") 
{
  OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(sqlCmd); 
  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

MessageBox.Show("done"); ```
````

If this solution improves the performance, please consider changing the SQL you create, with the following syntax:

```
 INSERT INTO stmast(...)
 SELECT [Records from the first dr2 row]
 UNION ALL
 SELECT [Records from the next dr2 row]
 UNION ALL
 SELECT [Records from the next dr2 row]
 [....]
```

Please refer also to this thread for more info and other possible solutions: [Multiple Insert statements in one connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867192/multiple-insert-statements-in-one-connection)

Comment: Nicola Lepetit not seem to run "characters found after end of sql statement"

Answer (score 0):

Open the database in Access and create an ODBC linked table to the source table in SQL Server. It will probably be given a name with a `dbo_` prefix like `dbo_stmast`.

Then create an Append query to append the rows from the linked source table into the destination table. It will look something like this:

[image: append query]

Then you can invoke that saved Append query from your C# app by calling it as a stored procedure:

```csharp
string connectionString =
      @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    + @"Data Source=C:\Users\Public\so59983979.accdb";
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "append_my_table";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"{rowCount} rows inserted in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
        // 10000 rows inserted in 1014 ms.
    }
}
```